# Org-mode: custom syntax for smallcaps, like *bold* and /italic/

Tags: org-mode, latex, formatting

I use org-mode a lot to export PDFs through LaTeX. How can I define a custom syntax for org-mode to mark small caps—so, for example, `^this^` gets translated to `\textsc{this}`, the way `*this*` gets translated to `\textbf{this}`?

Other ideas for the syntax:

- `<this>`
- `>this<`
- `#this#`
- `&this&`

I'm perfectly happy if this has no effect or ugly side effects in other export formats.

Comment: Best I can come up with for display: use `prettify-symbols-alist` and `prettify-symbols-mode` to replace `\textsc` with e.g. `<`, so `\textsc{this}` is rendered `<{this}`. Best I can come up with for entry: use yasnippets so `< TAB` inserts a `\textsc{|}` template, where `|` represents the insertion point.